# Updating the dataframe in python with modified values

Tags: python, pandas

I have written a code to do a date modification to reduce 1 day on 2/29/2008. 
The code successfully executes and shows me the output but it does not update the dataframe.

```
Name    Maint Start Date
Yasin   02/29/08
Susy    01/04/15
James   04/14/06
```

I wrote the below code it gave me the output but it did not update the dataframe

```
spend_sw[spend_sw['Maint Start Date'] == '02/29/2008'].apply(lambda x: pd.datetime(x['Maint Start Date'].year , x['Maint Start Date'].month, x['Maint Start Date'].day - 1), axis=1)
```

Then I modified it to but all the fields which did not have the leap year dat became blank.

```
spend_sw['Maint Start Date'] = spend_sw[spend_sw['Maint Start Date'] == '02/29/2008'].apply(lambda x: pd.datetime(x['Maint Start Date'].year , x['Maint Start Date'].month, x['Maint Start Date'].day - 1), axis=1)
```

Can you please tell me how can I modify the values to the  existing dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can first convert all values in column `Maint Start Date` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), then filter with [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) and subtract `Timedelta` one day created by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
print (spend_sw)
    Name Maint Start Date
0  Yasin         02/29/08
1   Susy         01/04/15
2  James         04/14/06

spend_sw['Maint Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(spend_sw['Maint Start Date'])

print (spend_sw.ix[spend_sw['Maint Start Date'] == '02/29/08', 'Maint Start Date'])
0   2008-02-29
Name: Maint Start Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

spend_sw.ix[spend_sw['Maint Start Date'] == '02/29/08', 'Maint Start Date'] = \
spend_sw.ix[spend_sw['Maint Start Date'] == '02/29/08', 'Maint Start Date'] - 
pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='d') 
print (spend_sw)
    Name Maint Start Date
0  Yasin       2008-02-28
1   Susy       2015-01-04
2  James       2006-04-14
```

Another solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [offset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#using-offsets-with-series-datetimeindex):

```
spend_sw['Maint Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(spend_sw['Maint Start Date'])

date = pd.to_datetime('02/29/08')
date1 = date - pd.offsets.Day(1)
#mask by condition
ma = spend_sw['Maint Start Date'] == date
spend_sw['Maint Start Date'] = spend_sw['Maint Start Date'].mask(ma, date1)
print (spend_sw)
    Name Maint Start Date
0  Yasin       2008-02-28
1   Susy       2015-01-04
2  James       2006-04-14
```

Comment: Hi...I tried the solution and it worked perfectly fine. Also I had to do some more date manipulations of adding years referring to an Name and it worked exactly how I needed it.